# ¿Cómo cargar scripts antes de Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo un script de un slider que tarda un tiempo en cargar y luego con AngularJS lo inicializo con datos traídos de la base de datos.

El problema es que a veces carga antes de Angular y otras veces no. usar un timeout no creo que sea la mejor manera.

Existe alguna manera de inyectar los scripts desde Angular y no desde la etiqueta ?

Gracias por ayudar :D

Comment: Si no añades tu código para reproducir el escenario es complicado ayudarte. Intenta añadir un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), aunque sea en un jsfiddle

Comment: Mi pregunta es cómo asegurarme de que un script cargue siempre antes de Angular, es algo más general

Answer (score 2):

Los scripts siempre se cargan y ejecutan en el orden en el que sus tags están añadidos en tu HTML:

```
<script src="/scriptA.js"></script>
<script src="/scriptB.js"></script>
```

El código de `scriptA.js` se ejecutará antes que el de `scriptB.js`, sea cual sea el tamaño de cada fichero (si `scriptB.js` se termina de cargar antes en paralelo, el navegador esperará de todos modos a que `scriptA.js` se termine de cargar y ejecutar). Si no fuese así sería imposible asegurarse de cargar las dependencias en el orden adecuado (por ejemplo JQuery y sus plugins).

NOTA: Esto deja de ser válido si

1. Inyectas dinámicamente un tag `script`, modificando el DOM para añadir un nuevo fichero o directamente añadiendo dentro de los tags nuevo código.
2. El tag `script` tiene un atribut `src` y usas el atributo `defer`, encuyo caso el código se ejecuta cuando el documento está completamente cargado.
3. El tag `script` tiene un atribut `src` y usas el atributo `async`, en cuyo caso el código se ejecutará en cuanto esté disponible.

Comment: interesante tu respuesta justo tenia ese problema antes, disculpa sabes angularJs?

Comment: Hace años que no lo toco, estoy usando Angular (v4)

Comment: Aa ok, pero tienes conocimiento que es lo importante, tu me puedes colaborar a solucionar un error que tengo en una directiva? :) si no estas ocupado

Comment: @Pablo Crea una pregunta y expón tu problema